# Добавление категории

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Программирую на Xcode. Как добавить категорию?

Comment: Дядь, чесссслово, Вас скоро начнут игнорировать с такой постановкой вопросов. Конкретизируйте ситуацию.
Какие категории? В чем? где? Используется ли база данных? В каком виде если да. Где категории сохраняются? Что такое вообще категории по Вашему?

Comment: С сайта netcoder.ru "Категория используется в случае, если вы хотите добавить поведение к классу без наследования от него. Т.е. категория позволяет расширить класс и добавить новые методы к нему и при этом не требуется исходных текстов класса, так же добавленные методы автоматически становятся доступными всем классам, унаследованным от изменяемого. Как обычно, вы начинаете с создания пары файлов содержащих интерфейс @interface и реализацию @implementation. Категория имеет свое имя, список методов и имя класса, который она расширяет."

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

Comment: А своими словами как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New File->Cocoa Touch->Objective-c category ->category name:name & category on: NSString(в вашем случае) Так всю дорогу было!

Comment: какой у вас xcode?

Comment: version 3.2.5

Comment: А чего он такой старый, можно сказать допотопный почему не 4.3.3? Если нет возможности создать категорию создайте класс NSObject и в файле .h пропишите #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (pars)

@end  а в файле .m пропишите #import "NSString+pars.h"

@implementation NSString (pars)

@end  только назовите свой класс  NSString+pars. да прибудет с вами сила!

Comment: Тут скобки,знаки препинания правильно стоят?
А то у меня ругается

    import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface NSString (pars)
    @end

Comment: Я пишу как вы говорите. У меня ругается на строчку

    -(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end {

Пишет следующее

>Expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: x86-64 Большое спасибо!Все работает!

Comment: И это хорошо :)